# Show that a circle of radius $r$ has radius of curvature equal to $r$

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

There is this statement from the book Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces by Do Carmo that I am trying to verify it myself.

The inverse $R=1/k$ of the curvature is called the *radius of curvature* at $s$. Of course, a circle of radius $r$ has radius of curvature equal to $r$, as one can easily verify.

So, I am trying to show that a circle of radius $r$ has radius of curvature equal to $r$:

Let $\alpha(s)=(r\text{ }\cos s, r\text{ }\sin s)$, for $r\geq0$ and $s$ is the arc length as the curve parametrisation.
Then $\alpha''(s)=(-r\text{ }\cos s, -r\text{ }\sin s)$, and $k=|\alpha''(s)|=r$.
So $R=1/k=1/r$.

Then how are we going to show that $R=r$?

I doubt that the statement should be a circle of radius $r$ has radius of curvature equal to 1? Am I correct?

Thanks for the help and clarification!

Comment: You only have that simple formula for the curvature if the curve is parametrised to have unit speed, $\lvert \alpha'(s)\rvert \equiv 1$. That is not the case here.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the comment. But the book says they will only use the curve parametrised by arc length for which $|\alpha'(s)|=1$ and they don't give any other formula.

Comment: But _your_ parametrisation is not by arc length. It's a constant multiple of arc length, which again makes things easy, but not  by arc length.

Comment: @DanielFischer oh yes you're right. But if I change it to $\alpha(s)=(\cos s, \sin s)$, then I cannot use it to show for any circle of radius $r$?

Comment: Well, no. But there's something else you can multiply. If we define $\beta(s) = \alpha(c\cdot s)$ for some $c\neq 0$, how are the speeds related?

Comment: @DanielFischer $\beta'(s)=c\cdot\alpha'(s)$? Then $|\beta'(s)|=c$?

Comment: Well, $\lvert \beta'(s)\rvert = c\cdot \lvert \alpha'(cs)\rvert$ (assuming $c > 0$). If $\alpha$ is not parametrised by arc length, like in your case, what could be a suitable $c$?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes $|\beta'(s)|=c\cdot|\alpha'(cs)|$. Is the suitable $c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}$? So, $|\beta''(s)|=1/r$?

Comment: Let $\beta(s) = (r\cos (cs), r\sin (cs))$. What is $\lvert \beta'(s)\rvert$?

Comment: @DanielFischer so $\beta'(s)=(-rc \sin (cs), rc \cos (cs))$, then $|\beta'(s)|=|rc|=rc$?

Comment: Right. And we want unit speed, so we will choose $c = \,?$

Comment: @DanielFischer $c=1/r$, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Daniel Fischer for the helpful comments.

The curve $\alpha(s)=(r\text{ }\cos s, r\text{ }\sin s)$ is not parametrised by arc length since $|\alpha'(s)|\neq1$

Hence we define a new curve $\beta(s)=\alpha(1/r\cdot s)$ for $r>0$. Then $\beta(s)=(r\text{ }\cos (1/r\cdot s), r\text{ }\sin (1/r\cdot s))$ and $\beta'(s)=(-\sin(1/r\cdot s), \cos(1/r\cdot s))$. So $|\beta'(s)|=1$. Furthermore, $\beta''(s)=(-1/r\text{ }\cos (1/r\cdot s), -1/r\text{ }\sin (1/r\cdot s))$, so $k=|\beta''(s)|=1/r$.

Hence $R=1/k=1/(1/r)=r$.